# How to display Relative layout content from top of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having following layout in file mylayout.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/Layout5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Layout6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/text_btn_1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/text_btn_2"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this layout when i am doing setContentView(R.layout.mylayout) for my activity, which has transparent theme, my layout is getting displayed in the center of the screen.

I want to change this layout positioning dynamically, so center(default) and bottom(by using following code) display is working.

```
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout6);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParas = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lLayout.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParas);
```

But somehow i am not able to figure out how to display this layout dynamically to the top of the screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: make android:layout_width & android:layout_height equal to match_parent

Comment: try "relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);"

Comment: Just Define theme in manifest for which ever activity you want to display content from Top. It removes title bar and covers whole screen. android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" and make the layout_width and Height attributes to match_parent or fill_parent in xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following fix for this issue.
I added filler Liner layout in the end under Relative layout.

To display in center don't do anything.

To display in top use following code. Just move filler layout to bottom.

```
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filler);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParas = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lLayout.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParas);
```

To display in bottom use following code. i.e. move layout6 to bottom.

```
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout6);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParas = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lLayout.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    lLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the rule that you made earlier (setting it to align bottom), and add a new rule:

```
//your code.
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout6);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParas = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) lLayout.getLayoutParams();
relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
lLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParas);

//remove rule
relativeParas.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
relativeParas.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParas);
```

Note that removeRule() is available from API 17 onwards.

Comment: this didn't work. I already tried and did it again after your suggestion.

Comment: Currently where does the layout go then?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying following way:

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/Layout5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/yellow"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="button2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

class:

```
 RelativeLayout Layout5 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout5);
 Layout5.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: I am having problem is displaying on upper half of the screen. Anyways i already tried Gravity Bottom.